# Firebase Recycler Adapter showing empty layout

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, adapter

Can someone help me please?
I'm building a chat based app and I have one tab witch is to show what group chat the user belongs, so when I retrieve those groups from Firebase it is suppose to bring only those that the user is participating. I managed to do that, but the problem is the layout is been inflated even with no information... Seen image below.

[The third empty block was not supposed to show up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGnnm.png)

[This is a pic of the group node on Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pu0hm.png)

This is the groupRef instance...

```
groupRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("groups");
```

This is my onBindViewHolder...

```
FirebaseRecyclerOptions options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Contact>().setQuery(groupRef, Contact.class).build();
    final FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Contact, GroupViewHolder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Contact, GroupViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final GroupViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Contact contact) {

            final String groupId = getRef(position).getKey();
            final String[] retImage = {"default_image"};

            groupRef.child(groupId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.exists()) {
                        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                            if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(userId)) {

                                if (snapshot.hasChild("image")) {
                                    retImage[0] = snapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();
                                    Picasso.get().load(retImage[0]).into(holder.groupImage);
                                }

                                final String groupName = snapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                                holder.groupName.setText(groupName);
                                holder.groupStatus.setText("Last seen: ");

                                holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View view) {

                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public GroupViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.contact_book_list_item, viewGroup, false);
            GroupViewHolder viewHolder = new GroupViewHolder(view);
            return viewHolder;
        }
    };
```

This is the view holder class

```
    public static class GroupViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    CircleImageView groupImage;
    TextView groupName, groupStatus;

    public GroupViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        groupName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textName);
        groupStatus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textPhone);
        groupImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagePersonIcon);
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the overridden getItemCount() method?

Comment: Don't have it. The tutorial I used as base to build this didn't have it either...

Comment: The only reason I can think of is that your FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Contact>().setQuery() is returning extra values. if you share how you have instantiated groupRef and a screenshot of your firebase database structure, it will be easier to help.

Comment: I just included both... check back on top.

Answer (score 0):

ther result you are getting is completely normal. you are checking for the children of the groupId child here:

```
groupRef.child(groupId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    ...
}
```

and there are 3 children there so everything is working fine. Now if you wanna show only the chikdren of groupId that have that specific user's name in them, you have to filter it and then send it to your adapter. So take the addValueEventListener{} out of the view binder completely, fetch all the available groups in the groupId, iterate through them and add the ones that have the user's name in them to an arraylist and then pass the arraylist to your adapter and show them in your onBindViewHolder{}

Comment: But I was only able to get the groupId because of the onBindViewHolder... How am I gonna get it outside of it? Also could you show me everything you said with the code itself? Because I'm still learning how to code, so its hard to follow what you're saying...